# How Do I Enable Turkish Letters In VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, turkish

As a programmer from Turkey, when i try to type a Turkish letter to my code (like ç,ş,ı,ğ,ü,ö)
it shows the letter as �. Is there a way to fix this by using an extension? Please let me know and thanks for your time.

Comment: which font are you using, try **Fira Code** or **Source Code Pro**

Comment: It says that i use Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace.

Comment: try a monospace font that has glyphs for your Turkish characters

Comment: You can ask @rioV8 to produce an answer, write your own, or delete the question (as long as there are no answers), instead of marking the title as {answered} yourself. I wouldn't delete it in this case.