# visual studio code output Turkish character problem

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, encoding, utf-8

`text.txt` file includes letters like "ğ", "ü", "ş",(these are Turkish letters). When I print the content, the result is ���

Here is my code in python:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
with open("text.txt") as file:
    contents=file.read()
print(contents)
```

output:

```
���
```

How can I solve this problem? Please let me know and thanks for your time.

I tried different encodes, *utf-8*, *windows1254*, etc. I tried firstly to decode and then encode but the letters were deleted. I think the problem is about VSCode because when I used PyCharm, it is OK. Turkish characters are not problem.

Additionally;
i tried "monospace" font, it didn't work

when i tried;
'with open("text.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:'
it gives an error:
'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 25: invalid start byte'

Comment: Try using `monospace` font that supports Turkish characters. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72380887/how-do-i-enable-turkish-letters-in-vscode.

Comment: The `coding` line declares the encoding of the source file. Use `open("text.txt", encoding="utf8")` to declare the encoding of the file you are reading. Use the actual encoding of the file if it isn’t UTF-8.

Comment: i tried monospace and encoding="utf8"  but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share  hexadecimal dump of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The vscode [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics) uses the system's built-in terminal, so it prints characters and displays related to many settings, such as your system language, terminal code page, vscode display language and so on.

##### Workaround

Use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. After installing the extension, use `Run Code (Ctrl+Alt+N)` to execute the script, and the code result will be display in the **OUTPUT** panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, İ've already used Code Runner, i reinstalled it, unfortunately it didnt solve the problem. i just write print("ü"), output: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: What if you use the code in the question? Read txt text content and then output.

Comment: text.txt: "ü", "ğ"  ;  output: "�", "�"